# Find parts of text with "find"

Tags: java, regex

I've a question regarding Java regex (Pattern, Matcher) and `find()`. Can I parse following text

```
Mo, We, Su 10:00 - 22:00
```

so that the first call of `find()` returns the following groups

```
group(1) = Mo
group(2) = 10:00
group(3) = 22:00
```

the second call of `find()` should return

```
group(1) = We
group(2) = 10:00
group(3) = 22:00
```

the third call of `find()` should return

```
group(1) = Su
group(2) = 10:00
group(3) = 22:00
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

**Assumptions**

- The days of week are written as `Mo`, `Tu`, `We`, `Th`, `Fr`, `Sa`, and `Su`.
- The time is valid. I will just match any sequence of digit in my regex.

**Solution**

You can use this regex (I allow the spacing to be flexible):

```
(Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su)(?=(?: *+, *+(?:Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su))* *+(\d+:\d+) *+- *+(\d+:\d+))
```

The regex above is very strict - it will not produce a match if the comma separated list contains something else between the current day of week to the time range (e.g. `Su, Somethingelse 02:12 - 3:45`).

If you are **totally sure** the format of the string is correct, and you just want to extract data, this loose regex is sufficient:

```
([a-zA-Z]+)(?=\D+(\d+:\d+)\D+(\d+:\d+))
```

Putting them into string literal:

```
"(Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su)(?=(?: *+, *+(?:Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su))* *+(\\d+:\\d+) *+- *+(\\d+:\\d+))"
"([a-zA-Z]+)(?=\\D+(\\d+:\\d+)\\D+(\\d+:\\d+))"
```

---

**Explanation**

```
(Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su)(?=(?: *+, *+(?:Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su))* *+(\d+:\d+) *+- *+(\d+:\d+))
```

- `(Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su)`: Match one of the days of the week.
- `(?=(?: *+, *+(?:Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su))* *+(\d+:\d+) *+- *+(\d+:\d+))`: A *zero-width* (text will NOT be consumed) positive look-ahead (if the pattern inside matches, then it can proceed; otherwise, fail the match and backtrack). It is specified by `(?=pattern)`.

  The pattern inside is `(?: *+, *+(?:Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su))* *+(\d+:\d+) *+- *+(\d+:\d+)`. Here, we are trying to match the part of text after the current day of week, and capture the time.

  - `(?: *+, *+(?:Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su))* *+`: After the day of week, we can have other day of weeks separated by commas.
  - `(\d+:\d+) *+- *+(\d+:\d+)`: Then comes the time range.
  - You can see a few  `*+` (space, asterisk, plus) sequence.  `*` means match 0 or more `*` of space character, *greedily*, however backtracking is allowed. The  `*+` is *possessive*, which means it disallows backtracking. You can think of it as an optimization to prevent unnecessary work to be done.

---

```
([a-zA-Z]+)(?=\D+(\d+:\d+)\D+(\d+:\d+))
```

For this one, I assume the days of week are the only sequences of alphabetical characters in the input string. I also assume that the timestamps are the only places that there can be digits.

Comment: look-ahead is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.